# Jenkins build jar size less than Maven built jar (Few classes and resources missing from Jenkins build)

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I have built Project locally through Maven and Jenkins. Size of jar built by 
     Jenkins is less than Maven built jar as Jenkin built jar doesn't have few 
     classes.
     What could be the root cause for this behavior of Jenkins?

Comment: If this is a fat jar, it is also possible that the SNAPSHOT versions differ between Jenkins and your local environment.

Answer (score 1):

The question is very vague, so I'll provide a series of reasons that can explain this, but its hard to answer exactly what happens.

Jenkins doesn't build anything by itself. The chances are that it just runs the maven command configured for it in job definition.
So you should check what exactly the command is, and re-run it locally. In the most simple case, you'll get the same results.
For this check the job definition itself or console output.

If you still have differences: Check all the profiles in pom.xml(s) maybe there are some profiles running on the Operating System that jenkins runs on.

Another possible reason: before running maven, jenkins probably checks out the code from repository (GIT, SVN or whatever) - so check the the "starting" codebase is ok and matches the codebase that you have locally